# regex on variable in bash script

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to cut out the prefix from a variable that represents path.

Currently this is my code:

```
for f in /Users/username/Documents/Dev/beneficiary-service/src/main/helm/*
do
  echo $f
  if [[ $f == 'values'* ]]
  then
      yq d -i $f 'resources.'
  fi
done
```

I printed $f to see its output. I expected it to be ONLY the filename, without the path (values-stg.yaml).
However, this is the output:

```
+ echo /Users/username/Documents/Dev/beneficiary-service/src/main/helm/values-stg.yaml
/Users/username/Documents/Dev/beneficiary-service/src/main/helm/values-stg.yaml
+ [[ /Users/username/Documents/Dev/beneficiary-service/src/main/helm/values-stg.yaml == \v\a\l\u\e\s* ]]
```

And also, the "if" statement will never be true, because it considers values* literally as is and not as "anything that starts with values"

Comment: Remove the path using parameter expansion: `[[ ${f##*/} == values* ]]`.

Comment: @Dominique Please take a look on my new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089998/sh-script-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-docker-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path expansion includes the whole path specified. You can remove it using parameter expansion

```
[[ ${f##*/} == values* ]]
```

> the "if" statement will never be true

That's not true. Quoting `values` is not needed, though, as none of the characters is special.

Comment: I took this into docker and got some changes, please take a look on my new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089998/sh-script-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

Use Basename - demonstration below - assigned output of basename "${f}" (in case of white space in file names)

```
for f in /Users/username/Documents/Dev/beneficiary-service/src/main/helm/*
do
  echo $f
  bf=$(basename "${f}") ; echo ${bf}
  if [[ ${bf} == 'values'* ]]
  then
      echo yq d -i ${bf} 'resources.'
  fi
done
```

Comment: Please take a look in my new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089998/sh-script-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-docker-container